# What's the best way to store unstructured text file for data mining

Tags: database, text, cloud

I have millions of text news on my machine. I want to do some text mining on it.

I want first to store thest text news in a more structured way. what's the best way to do it ? so It will become more convenient to do data mining later on.

Currently I just store these news file in database indexed by the news headlines and the file path.

Any suggestion will be really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That depends greatly on what you want to achive with the more structured data.

If the data size is not heavy, you could use "in text" search on your database and you are aldready done.

A category or "tag" like here on stackoverflow would help greatly to categorize and group your content, but I guess it is very hard to extract that from your pure text base now.

Also a simple timestamp (you could get from the file itself, but be wary some systems alter that date when files get copied...) could help too.

For content extraction, have a look at http://www.opencalais.com/ , it offers an api for "text" analysis you might find interesting.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just wonder that apart from database. Is there any method I don't know in data mining field. Just think of gmail. After open gmail, you can search any word on google search bar,and any email that contains the word will appear . I just want to know how the email be stored on the server.

Comment: Google uses MapReduce alot, cause they sit on huge amounts of data. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce for a short intro. I just did not mention it earlier, because I felt it was not required on your local maschine. If you have really huuuuge amounts of text you could have a look into map-reduce too. But I guess when your notes lie in one folder you could just do a textual search one by one and return all hit documents.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "do some text mining"?  Are you just looking to store the text?  Or, are you looking for a solution?

Many databases offer the capability to store text and do fast retrievals on them.

However, text mining typically covers a broader range of themes.  Here are some examples:

- Finding documents with similar themes.
- Exposing sentiment in the documents.
- Answering questions posed in natural language.
- Summarizing documents.
- Filling in data structures with information from documents.
- Using information from documents for predictive modeling purposes.
- Assigning codes to documents.

For such analyses, you would normally use text mining tools (you can look for these on [kdnuggets.com](http://www.kdnuggets.com/), for instance).  The tool then affects how the text is stored.

The last chapter of "Data Mining Techniques for Marketing, Sales, and Customer Support" is about text mining and has a very good case study on text mining applied to customer service records.

[In response to comment]

Is this an academic project or "real world"?  Is the text monolingual?  If so, is it English?  You definitely need to do some research.  Text analysis/mining has been an area of rather intense study since, at least, the time when Alan Turing proposed the Turing test in the 1930s.

As an example, I can readily think of four *very* different options for storing text for analysis.  The first is "as is", which is most useful if you have lots of processors and memory.  The second would be "grammatically", with text tagged with grammar and meanings, which is most effective if you have a team with lots of PhDs.  Third is as an inverted index, which is the basic form for searching and some proximity matching.  The fourth is by projecting onto an orthogonal space, using singular value decomposition (most useful if you want to use the text as input to other statistical techniques).

Comment: Thanks a lot. You gave me many hints. What I want to do is exactly you have listed above. I want to exposing sentiment or using information for predict model. But I currently I really don't want to use any mining tools . I prefer to program myself. Since I have millons of text, later will come more.  So I really want to think of a more efficient way to store these text. By the way ,some texts maybe a litte large.

Comment: Thanks, It's a project for real world. All the texts are in English. Currently I have think of maybe two ways to store. One is just store the whole text as a column in a relation database like SQL Server. Another is find a NOSQL database to store these text. All I want is the efficiency to store, search etc. What do you thin k

Comment: A column in a database should be fine.  If you are using a database such as mysql, SQL Server, or Oracle, you can include text search capabilities.